# Menu w/ Superfish - Links not working on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, superfish

I have a menu with jquery plugin superfish. The problem is that the links, in Chrome can't be clicked.

If I deactivate superfish menus work fine. I think it might be either z-index or markup but I can't find the error.

The link is: http://goo.gl/AkdXh

Can anyone take a look please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some script in onload_frontend.js which is preventing all links from working. Its binding to the click event on all a tags and cancelling the default action which would be to redirect to the url in the href. That code needs to be removed for the links to work.

```
$('a').click(function () {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

The menu links work in IE because the code doesnt work. The following error is raised when a link is clicked so default action is performed; i.e the page is redirected.

```
"Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'"
```

If you use the developer tools in the in IE and set a breakpoint on the code you will see the error.